# Return response as object in swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I have a function that connects to an API to retrieve data. The API takes two parameters accessCode (provided by user in a text box) and then UDID (UDID of their device). I can parse the data from within the function, but only locally. I need to store the values that are returned but am unsure on how to return them properly. Essentially I need this to return the json object as a dictionary (I think...) so it can be parsed outside of the async task. I've read through the swift documentation and that's where I found out how to do the requests, but I can't find a way to store the returned values in memory for access outside of the function.

```swift
func getResponse(accessCode:String, UDID:String, _ completion: @escaping (NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    let urlPath = "https://apihosthere.com/api/validate?accessCode=" + accessCode + "&UDID=" + UDID
    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else { return }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                let results = jsonResult as? NSDictionary
                print(results)
                completion(results!)
            }
        } catch {
            //Catch Error here...
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What calls this?  What does the passed `completion` look like?  Do your `results` print correctly?

Comment: You just want whatever value in ``results`` outside this if let function? Or you are failing at getting any value in ``results`` ? Also wouldnt it be better to make it into a JSON and then parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native `[String:Any]` and declare the type as optional to return `nil` if an error occurs.

And **never** use `.mutableContainers` in Swift, the option is useless.

```
func getResponse(accessCode:String, UDID:String, completion: @escaping ([String:Any]?) -> Void)) {
    let urlPath = "https://apihosthere.com/api/validate?accessCode=" + accessCode + "&UDID=" + UDID
    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else { return }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error else { 
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
            return 
        }
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                print(jsonResult)
                completion(jsonResult)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Your mistake is that you don't consider the closure, you have to execute the entire code inside the completion handler

```
@IBAction func StartWizard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Store entered access code
    let accessCode = AccessCodeField.text!
    //Call API to validate Access Code
    getResponse(accessCode:accessCode, UDID:myDeviceUDID) { [weak self] result in
        if let accessCodeFound = result?["Found"] as? Bool {
            print("Value of Found during function:")
            //If access code is valid, go to License view
            print(accessCodeFound)


            if accessCodeFound {
                //Load License View
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let licenseController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LicenseViewPanel")
                    self?.show(licenseController, sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK so the rest of the code has to be inside the completion handler, that makes sense. Is there a way of saving the values to also be accessible outside of it? Like if I wanted to store accessCodeFound and the other variables I have to make to store the rest of the values pulled from the API call, is there a way of making them global so they can be accessed on the next view controller?

Comment: Create a dictionary in the `LicenseViewPanel` controller and assign (unwrapped) `result` to it before the `show` line. However it's highly recommended to parse the JSON in a struct with `Decodable`.

Comment: Alright I will look into setting that up. Currently when I run the StartWizard function in your response I get an error: -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] must be used from main thread only" It seems that view controllers can only be changed on the main thread rather than in the async task. How would one get around that?

Comment: There's the money! Thank you so much for your help. I'll setup a decodable struc to hold the values

Answer (score 0):

Your `completion` closure should handle the obtained data. You would call the function like this:

```swift
getResponse(accessCode: "code", UDID: "udid", completion: { result in
    // Do whatever you need to do with the dictionary result
}
```

Also, I'd recommend you to change your `NSDictionary` with a swift `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the API returns as a response

```
{
    AccessCode = 00000000;
    Client = "0000 - My Company Name";
    EmailAddress = "brandon@brandonthomas.me";
    FirstName = Brandon;
    Found = 1;
    LastName = Thomas;
    Status = A;
    UDIDregistered = 1;
}
```

And this is what calls the function. I am calling at after clicking a button after an access code is being entered in a text field.

```
    @IBAction func StartWizard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Store entered access code
        let accessCode = AccessCodeField.text!
        var accessCodeFound: Bool? = nil
        //Call API to validate Access Code
        getResponse(accessCode:accessCode, UDID:myDeviceUDID) { result in
            accessCodeFound = result["Found"] as! Bool
            print("Value of Found during function:")
            print(accessCodeFound)
            //accessCodeFound = true
        }

        //If access code is valid, go to License view
        print("Value of Found after function:")
        print(accessCodeFound)
        //accessCodeFound = nil ???
        //it seems the value is getting reset after the function completes
        if accessCodeFound == true{
                //Load License View
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let licenseController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LicenseViewPanel")
                self.show(licenseController, sender: Any?.self)
            }
     }
```